# Token vs username/password autologin

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, token

What are the benefits of autologin with server-generated token if compare with autologin with encrypted username/password stored in cookies? what are the ways to improve token security on a browser? (Means store os, location etc.)

---

**UPDATE:** pls describe in which situations do we need oAuth?

Comment: A token can expire and be de-authorized. AKA sign me out everywhere, simple deletion of all the users tokens.

Comment: 1) Encrypted data can be *decrypted*; meaningless tokens can't be. 2) Server-managed tokens can be *tracked* and *invalidated* individually by the server; one global set of credentials cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server generated tokens can be tracked back to their origins. This enables a system to perform more comprehensive security tasks and user management than using a simple user name and password.

Tokens, for example, can decided to be expired after a certain period of time where the logins through saved user names/passwords cannot.

There is a risk that encrypted data can be decrypted. One can't get anything out of a server generated token on the contrary.

The employment of these techniques are only necessitated by your requirement to be low or high in the security management of your system. You can make your system tough and heavy - or simple and light if there is a low threat.

Comment: but the main risk is that someone will steal your token (or username/password) from cookies. For this threat they are equally secure, right?

Comment: The only way one can steal information from your cookies is to get access to the computer physically OR through session hijacking. Session hijacking can be prevented by end-to-end HTTPS encryption. The key here is that if someone manages to steal your password, he is in until you change it. But if someone steals your token, he is only in until server decided that is expired.